# Does passing -1 to query.get return None?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Am I guaranteed that `Table.query.get(-1)` returns `None`?

I couldn't find information on this in the documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the docs found at the link you posted:

> Return an instance based on the given primary key identifier, or None
>   if not found.

I would say, given you never insert an item with primary key(ident) of -1, **Yes**, it should always return **None**

Comment: So -1 is a valid primary key but will not be choosen by auto increment?

Comment: This sounds like a new question. Perhaps you could show your DDL defining the sequence. This link does show that using defaults, autoincrement starts at 1 and increments by 1: [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html?highlight=increment#sqlalchemy.schema.Sequence.params.increment).